# Android how to know if a button pressed with random sound that is playing

Tags: android, random, case

I want to make a kids playgame where i have various buttons, each one has a sound, i want to have only 1 button that play random sound, and the kids have to press the right animal button to get "right" message and then click again on random sound and play again.

So, to play random i have this working:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button cao,vaca;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final MediaPlayer sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cao);
        final MediaPlayer sound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gato);
        final MediaPlayer sound3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.galinha);

        cao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cao);
        vaca = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vaca);


        cao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(3) + 1;

                    //picking the right sound to play
                    switch (randomInt){
                    case 1: sound1.start(); 

                    break;
                    case 2: sound2.start();
                    break;
                    case 3: sound3.start();
                    break;
                    }


            }
        });





    }
```

and now for example how i do to if button pressed "vaca" do something, else do something inside the case random??

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(3) + 1;

                    //picking the right sound to play
                    switch (randomInt){
                    case 1: sound1.start(); 
                   // if button vaca pressed ....
                   // else....

                    break;
                    case 2: sound2.start();
                    break;
                    case 3: sound3.start();
                    break;
                    }
```

Comment: I don't think you are going to want your event handling code inside of a switch statement, those should be separate entities.

Comment: the only thing i want is to that children press the right animal button of the random sound he had  listen

Comment: no one can help me???

Answer (score 0):

Much too much code and objects.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button cao,vaca;
private MediaPlayer player;
```

...

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
```

...

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Resources resources = getResources();

             Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(3) + 1;
                if(player.isPlaying()) player.stop();
                //picking the right sound to play
                switch (randomInt){
                case 1: 
                   player.setDataSource(resources.openRawResource(R.raw.cao));
                break;
                case 2: player.setDataSource(resources.openRawResource(R.raw.gato));
                break;
                case 3: player.setDataSource(resources.openRawResource(R.raw.gatalina));
                break;
                }
                player.prepare();
                player.start();

        }
    });
```